# Convert to Pig Latin

Tags: c++, cstring

Need some help with converting string to PigLatin. Write a program that inputs two string variables, first and last, each of which the user should enter with his or her name. First, convert both strings to all uppercase. Your program should then create a new string that contains the full name in pig latin.
Here is my main func:

```
char* first = new char[MAX];
char* last = new char[MAX];
char* full = new char[MAX*2];

cout << "Enter first name: ";
cin.getline(first, MAX, '\n');
cout << "Enter last name: ";
cin.getline(last, MAX, '\n');

for(int i = 0; first[i]; i++)
{
first[i] = toupper(first[i]);
}
for(int i = 0; last[i]; i++)
{
last[i] = toupper(last[i]);
}

transformPigLatin(first);

transformPigLatin(last);

int offset = 0;
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<MAX && first[i]!=0; i++)
        full[offset++]=first[i];
    full[offset++]=' ';
    for (i=0; i<MAX && last[i]!=0; i++)
        full[offset++]=last[i];


transformPigLatin(full);
cout << full << endl;
```

And piglatin func (need help only with this function):

```
char* transformPigLatin(char* word)
{
int length = strlen(word);
char ch;
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){

if((length > 1) && (ch == 'a' || ch == 'A' ||ch =='e'||ch =='E'||ch =='i'||ch == 'I'||ch =='o'||ch =='O'||ch =='u'||ch =='U'))

{
strcat(word, "WAY");
}
else
{
    strcat(word, "AY");
}
return word;
}
}
```

These are two things I can't figure out how to do with c-string:

1)If the first letter is a consonant, move it to the end and add “ay” to the end.
2)If the first letter is a vowel, add “way” to the end.

Any tips will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are coding in C++, so you should use C++ strings rather than C strings.  Things are much easier with C++ strings.  The [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) class has many methods for manipulating the string content, including [`erase()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase) and [`append()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/append).

Try this:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

std::string first;
std::string last;
std::string full;

std::cout << "Enter first name: ";
std::getline(std::cin, first);
std::cout << "Enter last name: ";
std::getline(std::cin, last);

std::transform(first.begin(), first.end(), first.begin(), ::toupper);
std::transform(last.begin(), last.end(), last.begin(), ::toupper);

transformPigLatin(first);
transformPigLatin(last);

full = first + " " + last;
std::cout << full << std::endl;
```

```
void transformPigLatin(std::string &word)
{
    if (word.empty()) return;

    char ch = word[0];
    if ((ch < 'A') || (ch > 'Z')) return;

    if (std::string("AEIOU").find(ch) != std::string::npos)
    {
        word += "WAY";
    }
    else
    {
        if (word.length() > 1)
        {
             word.erase(0, 1);
             word.append(&ch, 1);
        }
        word += "AY";
    }
}
```

**Update**: if you *must* stick with C strings only, then try something more like this:

```
int getLine(char *prompt, char *word, int maxlen)
{
    if (prompt != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s", prompt);
        fflush(stdout);
    }

    if (fgets(word, maxlen, stdin) == NULL)
    {
        *word = '\0';
        return 0;
    }

    int length = strlen(word);

    if (word[length-1] == '\n')
    {
        word[length-1] = '\0';
        --length;
    }
    else
    {
        int ch;
        while (((ch = getchar()) != '\n') && (ch != EOF));
    }

    return length;
}
```

```
char* first = new char[MAX];
char* last = new char[MAX];
char* full = new char[(MAX*2)+1];

getLine("Enter first name: ", first, MAX);
getLine("Enter last name: ", last, MAX); 

for(int i = 0; first[i]; i++)
{
    first[i] = toupper(first[i]);
}

for(int i = 0; last[i]; i++)
{
    last[i] = toupper(last[i]);
}

transformPigLatin(first);
transformPigLatin(last);

strcpy(full, first);
strcat(full, " ");
strcat(full, last);

printf("%s\n", full);
```

```
void transformPigLatin(char* word)
{
    int length = strlen(word);
    if (length == 0) return;

    char ch = word[0];
    if ((ch < 'A') || (ch > 'Z')) return;

    if (strchr("AEIOU", ch) != NULL)
    {
        if ((length+3) >= MAX) return;
        strcat(word, "WAY");
    }
    else
    {
        if ((length+2) >= MAX) return;
        if (length > 1)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < length; ++i)
                word[i-1] = word[i];
            word[length-1] = ch;
        }
        strcat(word, "AY");
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the way you solved it, thank you. The problem is that I have to use only C string..That's why I'm confused!

Comment: @user3606582: If your class is teaching that, they are teaching C++ like it was 20 years ago. The rest of the world has progressed.

Comment: Other than the use of `cin` and `cout`, the rest of the code wasn't even using C++ at all, it was using C instead.

Comment: I added a C example to my answer.